# Error scraping a dynamic site with Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, html-table

[site source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt7AS.png)
[python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLok0.png)

I am trying scrape the text in every row of the source code provided. I was following this guide, but it looks like some of the syntax is outdated. https://youtu.be/UOsRrxMKJYk
When I add print(match.text) directly under for match in matches, I can successfully pull the desired data using the tr tag, but I get all of the data where I'm only looking for td[2] for every tr.

I've tried searching for alternatives to using the "." and replacing it with text like //tr/td[2] or matches/td[2] and cannot seem to locate the correct syntax for this case to display the text of the source code in a list.

Comment: Please post the html as a text, ant an screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.